# How to use the value of appSettings from App.Config file when creating a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am trying to create a Windows Server. I have some logic in C#

```
        string urlToPing = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["UrlToPing"].ToString();
        Stream data = client.OpenRead(urlToPing);
```

I need to read

Here my App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UrlToPing" value="http://mysite.com"/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

I am new at Windows Services, my questions:

- When I publish to folder the Service or if I create a build I cannot
  see the App.Config file

  - Visual Studio warning on ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings as obsolete (what should I use instead?)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To my second question I found a solution:

1. Add a reference to System.Configuration to your code file.

   `using System.Configuration;`
2. The setting may now be referenced correctly...

   `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlToPing"].ToString();`

Answer (score 4):

To your first question, when you build a executable project (Windows Service, Console Application, etc) it will rename the app.config to "YourApplication".exe.config where "YourApplication" is the name of your Startup assembly. It will then copy the file to your output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add System.Configuration to references

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add "using System.Configuration;"
2. Upper/lower case important
3. Moreover attention this point; you must use "appSettings" tag that after than  "configurations" tags.

[image: Appsettings - screenshot]

Comment: Make sure you upload images to Stack Overflow so they are visible if not the image is too big. 

Your answer is general advice of how to use app settings, the question was how to include the config file to the published service and avoid warnings.